# how to programmatically find game center friends in IOS 8

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

My app is a multiplayer game that only invited friends can play.  So, I would prefer to implement a custom match making view controller.  However, I am unsure how to programmatically determine the friends of the `GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer`.  Previously one could use `loadFriendsWithCompletionHandler` but it was deprecated in IOS 8.  How would I do this now?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `loadFriendPlayersWithCompletionHandler:`